# Spring POJO Service Transaction When calling EJB2, EJB3 services, Hibernate DAO, JPA DAO

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, ejb, spring-transactions

We are building a system on top of a bunch of:

- Legacy EJB2 services
- EJB3 services
- POJO spring services with Hibernate DAO
- POJO spring services with JPA DAO - hibernate JPA implementation

The new system is based on struts2 + spring, my question is when I call these services in action or in a service facade, how do I make transaction work properly?

For example, I am want to transaction like

```
Begin Transaction
     - call some EJB2 service, like ejb2Service.addPeople(....);
     - call some EJB3 service, like ejb3Service.updateDepartment(....);
     - call spring POJO service with Hibernate DAO, springHibernateService.deleteOldRecords(...);
     - call spring POJO service with JPA DAO, like springJPAService.addNewOrderNumber(....)
End Transaction
```

Is this even possible?  I have no clue because it involves so many different tech stack and each one has its own approach of managing transaction. Because I am not familiar with transaction stuff, really hope someone could share some ideas or references etc.

Thanks.

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't be calling this from your action but from your service layer, which in turn would be transactional.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, agree. But we don't want to add more EJB services, instead, we want to use spring POJO service. But can spring service transaction management handles these different transaction paradigm together? Thanks!

Comment: Where did I mention more EJB services? I nowhere mentioned the word EJB. For Spring it doesn't matter as long as you configure the proper transaction manager and proper integration for the different frameworks.